# Multiple requests, same response

Tags: angularjs, rest, deferred

I'm facing this strange issue with the $http service: every request made to the API provided on the company that I work, wrapped in a $q.all(), return the same response.

```
var promises = [
    $httpPromiseA(),
    $httpPromiseB(),
    $httpPromiseC()
];

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function (response) {
        $log.log(response);
    });

// $log.log returns [expectedObjectFromA, expectedObjectFromA, expectedObjectFromA]
```

This occurs randomly: the expectedObjectFromA can be expectedObjectFromB or expectedObjectFromC. The fact is that all of the three objects return the same, or two of one and one of other, etc.

If I chain one after other, in a linear manner, they all work perfectly, but takes more time to acomplish the task, of course.

```
var def = $q.deferred();
var resolvedData = [];

$httpPromiseA()
    .then(function (response) {
        $log.log(response);

        resolvedData.push(reponse);

        return $httpPromiseB();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $log.log(response);

        resolvedData.push(reponse);

        return $httpPromiseC();
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        $log.log(response);

        resolvedData.push(reponse);

        return def.resolve(resolvedData);
    });

return def.promise();

// $log.log returns [expectedObjectFromA],
// [expectedObjectFromB] and [expectedObjectFromC]
// as expected. ResolvedData brings [expectedObjectFromA,
// expectedObjectFromB, expectedObjectFromC].
```

Can you give me some directions on what may be happening here?

I'm using the core implementations of $http and $q. I've tried one $q.allSettled, applied as $decorator, based on the API resource of Kris Kowalk's Q, but didn't succeed too.

Thanks.

## EDIT 1:

I cannot pass the arguments to the functions separately because it's a wrapper function thats call the `$http` service, here in my app. The wrapper function expects a `String` as the first argument, and an `Object` as the second. The wrapper function returns the `$http` calls.

## EDIT 2:

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4kYFU449ueLUt71bF9N5) calls 2 concurrent requests, one to the Instagram API and the other to the Flickr API. The problem don't occur is this Plunker. I really don't know how to deal with this trouble. This is REALLY annoying.

Comment: var promises = [     $httpPromiseA(),     $httpPromiseB(),     $httpPromiseC() ];  $q.all(promises)     .then(function (responseA, responseB,  responseC) {         $log.log(response);     });  // $log.log returns [expectedObjectFromA, expectedObjectFromA, expectedObjectFromA].      You need to catch each response from promise separately. Try the above changes in code hope it works

Comment: @CoderJohn you have seen the question? Your solution doesn't make sense. Try to handle a `$q.all()` like you suggested...

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to work-around a buggy/broken API, that sometimes breaks when you try to use concurrent requests?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I'm thinking that this can be my problem, but I need to prove it in a meaningful way, you understand? I'll provide one example in Plunker, but the environment will not be the same, which will not be precise enough to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the server side, which was having problems with simultaneous requests, answering all made together with the same response.

Thanks for all support and attention.

Answer (score 0):

In $q.all you'll want to pass in an array of promises, instead executing the function. $httpPromiseA.$promise instead of $httpPromiseA() and so on.

Comment: so how I'll pass any arguments to these functions? In every function they need their arguments. This too doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: `var parameters = {}:
var promiseA = $httpPromiseA(parameters);
$q.all([promiseA.$promise, ... , .... ]);`

Comment: I cannot pass the arguments that way because it's a wrapper function thats call the `$http` service, here in my app. The wrapper function expects a `String` as the first argument, and an `Object` as the second. The wrapper function returns the `$http` calls.

Comment: I think the point here is that $q.all() requires either a promise or an array of promises. You'll have to adjust your code in order to use $q.all(). It will be difficult to assist you further unless you provide more code examples. Perhaps setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've made the modifications that you suggested with no success. I'll provide one example in Plunker.